# OpenJDK not working in Ubuntu 12.10 on Firefox

Tags: firefox, java, openjdk, icedtea

This is a problem I've been facing for quite some time now : installing Java.

I have installed the following packages using Synaptic

```
icedtea-netx
openjdk-7-jre
```

A few others got installed along with it like `icedtea-netx-common` and a few others...
But the thing is, the Java site still tells me that Java isn't installed.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 and Firefox. Any help regarding this?

Comment: Do you specifically want the OpenJDK? If not then look at the Oracle Java which is maintained by the webupd8 team. See: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked that your Java plugin is enabled in Firefox? Go to Tools / Add-ons / Plugins, and validate that it is enabled.

Comment: Thanks, apparently the `icedtea-plugin` package also had to be installed. Silly me.